# Makefile. Dependency that makes more dependencies

Tags: makefile

Consider this makefile:

```
srcs = 1.src

%.compiled: create_srcs $(srcs)
    @echo $@ depends on: $^

create_srcs:
    $(eval srcs = $(srcs) 2.src)
    @echo srcs: $(srcs)

%.src:
    @echo src: $@
```

If executed it outputs:

```
c:\>make file.compiled
srcs: 1.src 2.src
src: 1.src
file.compiled depends on create_srcs 1.src
```

How do I make `%.compiled` depend on `2.src` also?

Also, if it matters, in my real makefile `create_srcs` unpacks some zips which may contain sources and 'srcs' variable is defined as `srcs = $(shell find ...)`. `%.compiled` is not the final target, though `create_srcs` is the first one.

Comment: The `$(eval srcs = ...)` thing is useless because it's part of a recipe, and by the time it runs the makefile is already fully parsed.

Comment: @MichaelLivshin I did realize that but your comment pushed me in the right direction :). Seems like I need recursive make here to reparse the file...

Comment: Although this is a very old question it came back up somehow. If there still is interest: can you describe the logic behind introducing `2.src` ad hoc in another target? Is this new target really emerging dynamically throughout the recipe executions or is it known at the start of `make` that `2.src` will eventually become a target ?